# Accidentally deleted my app launch screen

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I deleted the launch screen on the app awhile ago, but now I want one back.  How can I create a new one without disrupting my main.storyboard?

Comment: This is what source code control and backups are for. If you are not doing both, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Create new launch screen through your Xcode

[image]

And make it launch screen on your app General screen

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Right click on you project folder, then create a new storyboard named launch screen, Then add that as bellow image showing

Answer (score 0):

Go to trash and you can see the today deleted item. there is function to **Put Back**. if put back is not there then you can copy the item and paste in **Base.lproj** folder and add this in the xcode.

[image]